# Spree: how to get the current order for a user without their session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm looking for a way to get the current order for a particular user within a webhook controller so that I can apply a promotion to it. Since it's a webhook controller, I won't have access to the session for the user whose order I need, so I won't be able to use the `current_order` method within `Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order` . I'm using spree 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic may provide what you're looking for:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/11a24a823780dbc63708b9ba840f4e7696202dc2/core/config/initializers/user_class_extensions.rb#L22-L24

You could also pass the Spree::Order ID along to your webhook controller, and just use that to find the order.